# Bookshelf.js orderby items randomly using rand()

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using bookshelf.js to develop a project using mariaDB. I want to get my post items ordered randomly. I found this solution works for knex.js

```
knex('posts').select('id', 'text')
            .orderByRaw('RAND()')
            .limit(100)
```

But I want to do the same thing with Bookshelf.

Comment: actually its random() not rand(), just wanted to say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to bookshelf.js documentation, model.query() returns the underlying knex query builder which you can apply your knex solutions to.

```
Post.query(function (qb) {
            qb.select('id',  'text');
            qb.orderByRaw('RAND()')
            qb.limit(2);
        }).fetchAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will be helpful to someone :

```
//with where 
    let val = await Question.where({'test_id': id}).query(function (qb) {
                qb.limit(1);//with limit
                qb.orderByRaw('RAND()')//with rand
            }).fetchAll({
                withRelated: ['answers', 'comments'], require: true
            });
```